# Tensorflow variable value

Tags: tensorflow, variables

I cannot see the value of a variable in Tensorflow. For example, if I assign a variable like this: v = tf.Variable(initial_value = [1,2]) and then type v, I get
<tf.Variable 'Variable_6:0' shape=(2,) dtype=int32>. If I use v.numpy I get <bound method BaseResourceVariable.numpy of <tf.Variable 'Variable_6:0' shape=(2,) dtype=int32>>.
How can I see the value assigned to a variable in Tensorflow?

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. In general, you will want to exhaust all resources before coming here and posting a question. Your particular question can be answered by simply reading the [Tensorflow documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/variable) about tf.Variables. You need to call `v.numpy()` not `v.numpy`

Answer (score 0):

You can see value of variables as shown below

```
import tensorflow as tf
v = tf.Variable(initial_value = [1,2]) 
v.numpy()
```

Output:

```
array([1, 2], dtype=int32)
```